# Is this stochastic equation numerically solvable?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

My knowledge of Stochastic ODEs is poor at best, but I have a problem I need to solve. I've boiled it down to a more straightforward scaler form.

$dX_t = e^{-X_t}X_t+dW_t e^{-X_t}$

I was wondering if this is tractable, even in the numerical sense. I'm a bit new to all of this so book suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: The Ito formula could be a start. Otherwise one can approximate solutions via the Euler-Maruyama method.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $dt$ term?